# Present a logarithm in terms of two logarithms

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, algebra

If $\log _8 3=p$  and  $\log _3 5=q$ then, in terms of  $p$  and  $q$, what does $\log _{10} 5$  equal?  I tried by my hand, I get the answer is $\dfrac{3pq}{1+3pq}$.  How can I tell Mathematica solve it?

With Maple, I see here

https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/220264-How-Do-I-Find-A-Logarith-In-Term-A-Given

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a single built-in function for the task, but I can think out a solution involving a bit manual analysis.

First use `PowerExpand`:

```
eq = {Log[8, 3] == p, Log[3, 5] == q} // PowerExpand
(* {Log[3]/(3 Log[2]) == p, Log[5]/Log[3] == q} *)

expr = PowerExpand@Log[10, 5]
(* Log[5]/(Log[2] + Log[5]) *)
```

Then it's clear we just need to solve for `Log[2]` and `Log[5]` from `eq`. This can be done by:

```
freeze = Log -> Inactive[Log];

rule = {eq, Log@{2, 5}} /. freeze // Apply@Solve
(* {{Inactive[Log][2] -> Inactive[Log][3]/(3 p), 
  Inactive[Log][5] -> q Inactive[Log][3]}} *)

expr /. Activate@rule[[1]] // Simplify
(* (3 p q)/(1 + 3 p q) *)
```

I've used `Inactive` to *freeze* `Log` because `Log[2]`, etc. cannot be used as 2nd argument of `Solve`.

---

You can of course build a general solver for the same class of problem:

```
help[lst_, target_] := (
  expr = PowerExpand@target;
  eq = PowerExpand@lst;

  findlog = Union@Cases[#, _Log, Infinity] &;

  argu = findlog@expr;
  argu2 = Complement[findlog@eq, argu];

  freeze = Log -> Inactive[Log];

  rule = {eq, argu, argu2} /. freeze // Apply@Solve // Quiet;

  expr /. Activate@rule[[1]] // Simplify)
```

Example:

```
help[{Log[8, 3] == p, Log[3, 5] == q}, Log[10, 5]]
```

$$\frac{3 p q}{3 p q+1}$$

```
help[Log[{2, 3, 7}, {3, 5, 2}] == {a, b, c}, Log[140, 63]]
```

$$\frac{2 a c+1}{a b c+2 c+1}$$

```
help[Log[{140, 3, 7}, {6, 5, 2}] == (Subscript[a, #] & /@ Range[3]), Log[2, 3]]
```

$$\frac{a_3-a_1 \left(2 a_3+1\right)}{\left(a_1 a_2-1\right) a_3}$$

```
help[Log[{140, 3, 7, 2}, {6, 5, 2, 66}] == (Subscript[a, Range[4]] // Thread), 
 Log[11, 12]]
```

$$\frac{a_1 \left(2 \left(a_2-1\right) a_3-1\right)-a_3}{a_1 \left(a_3 \left(a_2 \left(a_4-1\right)+2\right)+1\right)-a_3 a_4}$$

I doubt if this makes much sense, though…